# what is the log step in magento2 migration?

Tags: magento2, data-migration

I am migration M1 to M2 using the data migration tool.

what is the Log step actually?

In M1 many log_* exists but in M2 there are no log tables available.
What is actually done in this step?

```
     [2020-03-02 17:31:20][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: 
     Url Rewrite Step]: started
     100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
     [2020-03-02 17:31:21][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration] 
      [step: Log Step]: started
     9% [==>-------------------------] Remaining Time: 4 days
```

Comment: i think no need to migrate logs

Comment: How can skip it?

Comment: yes in config.xml file comment log step

Comment: already magento add log_*  tables in ignore list.

Does need to add any additional thing to skip it?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Did you ever find out which other tables are included in this 'log step', and if any of those are essential/important?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced similar issue. I truncated log and report tables in local instance of M1 db and initiated the migration.

You can either truncate or ignore below tables in map.xml and re initiate migration step

1. report_viewed_product_index
2. report_compared_product_index
3. report_event catalog_compare_item
4. dataflow_batch_import
5. dataflow_batch_export
6. catalog_compare_item